# How to add fragment to activity from another class in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to make it possible to add fragments to the container (FrameLayout) of the activity by calling some methods of the activity.

So here is a simplified version of my activity class:

```
public class TermsAndConditionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static TermsAndConditionsActivity           instance;
private static boolean                              loggedIn;
private TermsAndConditionsListener                  termsAndConditionsListener;

private TermsAndConditionsFragment                  termsAndConditionsFragment;
private ReadTermsAndConditionsFragment              readTermsAndConditionsFragment;
private Terms                                       terms;
private User                                        user;
protected FragmentManager                           fragmentManager;

public TermsAndConditionsActivity() {}

public static TermsAndConditionsActivity getInstance(Terms terms, User user, boolean loggedIn, TermsAndConditionsListener termsAndConditionsListener) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance                            = new TermsAndConditionsActivity();
        instance.terms                      = terms;
        instance.user                       = user;
        instance.loggedIn                   = loggedIn;
        instance.termsAndConditionsListener = termsAndConditionsListener;
    }
    return instance;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_no_drawer);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    prepareReadTermsAndConditionsFragment();
    prepareTermsAndConditionsFragment();
}

private void prepareTermsAndConditionsFragment() {
    if (termsAndConditionsFragment == null) {
        if (loggedIn) {
            termsAndConditionsFragment = TermsAndConditionsOnlineFragment.newInstance(termsAndConditionsListener);
        } else {
            termsAndConditionsFragment = TermsAndConditionsAnonymousFragment.newInstance(termsAndConditionsListener);
        }
    }
}
private void prepareReadTermsAndConditionsFragment() {
    if (readTermsAndConditionsFragment == null) {
        readTermsAndConditionsFragment = ReadTermsAndConditionsFragment.newInstance(terms, user, termsAndConditionsListener);
    }
}

public void openTermsAndConditions() {
    initFragment(termsAndConditionsFragment);
}

public void openReadTermsAndConditions() {
    initFragment(readTermsAndConditionsFragment);
}

private void initFragment(TermsAndConditionsFragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentTransaction();
        ft.add(getContainerId(), fragment, fragment.getTagString()).commit();
    }
}

protected FragmentTransaction getFragmentTransaction() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    return ft;
}

public static void startActivity(Context context, int flags) {
    if (context != null) {
        Intent launchIntent                 = getIntent(context, flags);
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}

public static Intent getIntent(Context context, int flags) {
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, TermsAndConditionsActivity.class);
    launchIntent.addFlags(flags);
    return launchIntent;
}
}
```

THe activity class works fine for creating the layout of the activity, which is basically a Framelayout for holding fragments.

The problem is that, if I call the method "openTermsAndConditions()" from outside the activity class, nothing happens. But if I call it from onCreate in the activity class, it is added correctly. I would like to be able to add these from outside the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create global instances it leads to memory wastage,create them only in the methods scope needed and in your case you don't need the fragment instances globally since you use it only once.

Try this

```
public void addYourFragment()
 {
     Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TermsAndConditionsFragment.class.getSimpleName()); 
   if(fragment == null)
   {
     fragment = new TermsAndConditionsFragment();
   }
    if(fragment not added)
    {
    //call you initFragment,remove the first line in that and pass the Fragment parameter
     initFragment(Fragment fragment)
     {
      //do add or replace and make this common method for all your fragments to be added don't use too many methods for each diff fragments to be added
      }
 }
```